# Keras loop is producing unexpected predictions results

Tags: keras, generator, prediction

I'm trying to create a test time augmentation in Keras. I'm testing my code without performing any image augmentation. It loops through my dataframe 5 times with all rows evaluated on each loop.  The accuracy of the first loop is great!  The accuracy of loops 2 to 5 are 10 times worse then the predictions made in loop 1.  The `flow_from_dataframe` has `shuffle=False`.

I have also tested the code with appropriate image augmentation in the `ImageDataGenerator` function. I get similar results with good accuracy in the fist loop and 10X worse accuracy in loops 2 to 5. Do you have any suggestions about why there's a change in performance? Is the order changing?

```
TTA_data_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                        fill_mode='nearest')

TTA_generator = TTA_data_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=train_df2,
                    target_size=(96,96),
                    x_col='img_path', 
                    y_col='label', 
                    class_mode="binary",  
                    batch_size=20,
                    shuffle=False)
predictions = []
predict_steps_per_epoch= len(train_df2.label) /20
for i in range(5):
   preds = final_model.predict_generator(TTA_generator, steps=predict_steps_per_epoch)
   predictions.append(preds)
```

Comment: can i know why model.predict_generator is inside a for loop? , even with the shuffle it should give the same accuracy every time because the weights in the model and the test set are not changed.

Comment: I would like to perform some image augmentation and perform multiple predictions on the same image.  The final prediction will be the average of the augmented image prediction.  I am currently not performing any image augmentation except for the necessary rescale.  I think I should get the same prediction out in each prediction of the for loop.  However, I am not.  The first iteration of the loop produces good results, but the rest of the iteration perform poorly.  It is like my data is getting shuffled but shuffle=False.